vite works in dev but not after build
I have a react vite v5 application, it works fine in dev mode, when i build the app, it builds without anu errors but the app doesn't work
i get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'spawn')
    at index-Bx4XYcFH.js:208750:21

after running :
# vite build
# vite preview

i had a buffer and a global bug, but i pollyfilled the vite config and it got fixed.
here is my vite config:
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { nodePolyfills } from "vite-plugin-node-polyfills";
import { VitePWA } from "vite-plugin-pwa";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    svgr(),
    nodePolyfills(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
    mainFields: ["module"],
  },
  server: {
    open: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
  build: {
    target: "esnext",
    minify: false,
    outDir: "build",
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        "utils"
      ],
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ["**/*.svg", "**/*.svgo"],
    esbuildOptions: {
      define: {
        global: "globalThis",
        fs: "fs",
      },
      plugins: [
        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
          buffer: true,
          process: true,
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
  define: {
    global: "globalThis",
  },
});

There is not way i can find the library or the code causing this bug

And 'spawn' does not appear anywhere in your project? And what do you mean "it doesn't work but it builds without errors"? When does the error you posted appear?
